# Import javascript from module file created by NX

Tags: javascript, import, module

Currently I'm making first step with NX. I followed this very basic tutorial:
https://nx.dev/getting-started/tutorials/package-based-repo-tutorial
and was able to create this small javascript:

```
"use strict";
const exports = {};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.isEven = void 0;
var isEven = function (x) { return x % 2 === 0; };
exports.isEven = isEven;
```

(I had to add the second line `const exports = {};` manually but this is not the core of my question.)
Now I researched and read a lot but I'm not able to include or import this for use in a script tag in my html file. My latest approach:

```
    <script type="module">
        import isEven from "../packages/is-even/dist/index.js";
    </script>
```

Shurely I'm missing something basic but all of the resources I read are confusing and I didn't completely understand.
This is not related to NX only as I encountered other modules using the same syntax. I used a workaround by assigning `exports` to a global variable but this seems to be not a clean solution.

Comment: Your code is mixing up two different module mechanisms. There's CommonJS, which uses `require()` and the module-global `exports` variable, and then there's the native ES6 module system, which uses the `import` and `export` keywords. They are not the same.

Comment: Note that the tutorial you linked in your question *clearly* uses ES6 module syntax.

Comment: OK, the first snippet is code that is given from NX or other sources and I have to take it as is. The second one is my humble attempt. In what way do I have to modify the second one to make it work?

Comment: No it is not; *look at  the source tutorial you posted in your own question!!* That code uses ES6 `export` syntax, not CommonJS.

Comment: No answers? Too bad! Apparently there is no support for this subject.

Comment: You code does not export anything.  If you want to import from the module with `import`, then you have to export with an `export` statement. Creating a variable called "export" is not at all the same thing.